# Cannot delete Ubuntu as a EFI Boot Device

Tags: uninstall

I use a Lenovo Yoga 300 something.. Can't remember which, but I recently installed Ubuntu to have as an alternate OS. After a while, I noticed a few limitations to it, and issues that the Internet couldn't fix.
I googled how to get rid of it, and people said to delete the partitions. Great. I did that, but when I booted the laptop, Grub would come up. I found a solution to get rid of it, but Ubuntu is still a EFI device. I have tried using everything to remove it, including resetting my laptop. I did the command prompt thing, and it pops up in there, but everytime you try and delete it, it'll either say successful and come back or will say action failed. Now this wouldn't matter much if I was keeping the laptop, but I'm not. It's going to my mother, and she doesn't understand much about computers, nor the current need to spam F12 at start up to load boot devices. Ubuntu and Windows are both labelled with the same WDC WD5000LPCX-24C6HT0 legacy hard drive name. I have no idea how to fix it and don't want to do something so far fetched I break the laptop. Help?
The Version of Ubuntu was 17.10 Desktop
I've been trying bcedit and using the diskpart stuff
Nothing has been working

Comment: Please edit your question to include the version of Ubuntu, the commands that you're using, and the output that the error messages are generating, as they will help others troubleshoot your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Grub is installed in the EFI partition. you need to manually delete it.

Boot a LiveCD, and use gparted to temporarily remove the ESP flag from the EFI partition.

Open the EFI partition and delete the folder /EFI/ubuntu.
Use gparted to set the ESP flag again and reboot.

Comment: So basically, I need to 'try' Ubuntu, and somehoe open gparted? Can you make this a more idiot proof explanation

Comment: yes, gparted is in the menu

Comment: I was looking with easyUEFI, ubuntu is there, but when you open the drive it's listed under (EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi) it doesn't exist

Comment: and grubx64.efi? and the folder? you are looking in the efi system partition yes? where efi/windows also exists

Comment: In the drive there is 3 main folders. BOOT EFI and System Volume Info. In EFI there is boot and Microsoft, one obviously being Windows. In Boot, there is two files, bootx64.efi and fbx64.efi. In Microsoft, there is boot and Recivrry, full of folders and dlls, also BCD logs

Comment: ok, easyUEFI should be able to delete the ubuntu entry from the EFI table. Also in the firmware settings, you can select Windows as the booting OS

Comment: I tried Deleting it, it comes up with errors. Also, Ubuntu always boots up priority wise and when I try changing priorities it will always reset

Comment: what error do you get? this appears to be a hardware issue

Comment: Failed to run system API.(0x04D3001500C60000)

Comment: can you do a clean install of windows?

Comment: I have reset the laptop, and I can also make a windows install usb

Comment: sorry, this is a windows or a hardware issue. I am unable to give more help other than reinstall windows and see what you get.